# sudo script - best practice?

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I have a script in which some of the commands need to be run as sudo.
I have seen it [asserted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-sudo-command-inside-a-script#comment552406_425990) that running sudo inside scripts is a bad idea, and that is is better to run the whole script as sudo (and then possibly modify sudoers for convenience, [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password)).

I have thought about it, and can't actually see any reason *not* to run sudo commands inside scripts. Assuming the script and its directory are both owned by root, and therefore unadulterated, I can't see any difference, from a security point of view. (And even if it were, running the whole script as sudo would be no less dangerous). Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think one benefit to running sudo outside of the script is allowing for interactive password input. A password prompt inside a script may not be seen, or the user may not want to wait for that section. That said, the less that's running as root, the smaller the attack surface.

Comment: Is there any reason for not running the script as sudo so you can skip this? Since you are running sudo commands, I don't see the problem

Comment: @JeffSchaller That's true, though if that's the only reason it certainly doesn't apply to the majority of scripts I run.

Comment: @SauceCode Consider that password prompts are the problem, and that scripts that rely on sudo inside aren't portable to other environments - while that may not apply to you it applies to a majority of *nix variants that don't include sudo.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Why wouldn't the password prompt be seen when `sudo` is inside the script?

Comment: @Barmar I imagine a long-running process preceding the sudo section; the user may want to start the overall script in a screen (or other background mechanism) and not interact with it until it completes.

Comment: Of course, if you're going to leave the script running unattended, you wouldn't put any request for input late in the script. That's just good UI design, not specific to sudo or security.

Comment: If you later use your script in a pipe or run it from a gui, then stdin/stdout probably won't be connected to your terminal/screen. That's why I often use kdesudo (gksudo) instead. Putting sudo outside the script doesn't fix this, but you find out if it's a problem sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo` is a bad idea because you don't know what will happen and if it's really necessary:

- Will a password prompt be shown? If so, who is going to type a password? Remember: your script may be run in a shell by a human, but could also be run in background, at startup, by cron or in other situations where a terminal is not available.
- Will the user type her password if she sees the prompt? Personally, I would immediately stop scripts asking me for a password. Also, I may not even notice the prompt if your script produces a lot of output.
- Is `sudo` available and configured? Can the current user run `sudo`? The answer to one of these question may be 'no', in which case you should let the user choose how to give your script the necessary privileges.
- Are you sure you need to be superuser? Maybe I configured my system so that your script does not need root privileges at all, in which case `sudo` is totally unnecessary and can be very disturbing.

Please let *me* decide what privileges you need and how to give them to you.

Running `sudo` may be a good idea if you're root and you want to *drop* your privileges. For example, you may open a file that is owned by root and then immediately switch to `nobody:nogroup` for security reasons. Still, the problem that `sudo` may not be available or may not be configured remains.